# SSH closed in 120 minutes when wget one file

Tags: ssh, centos, timeout, wget

In CENTOS7, I use wget command to get one file. But ssh session will be closed in 120 minutes. In every 20 minutes, the following information appeared.

```
Tue Jun  2 06:40:01 2020
Your terminal (/dev/pts/0) has been idle for 63 min.
Press Enter key or you will be logged out any time after 56 min.
```

I modifed the parameter in /etc/ssh/sshd_config as following:

```
ClientAliveInterval      60
ClientAliveCountMax     5000000000000
```

But the problem does still exist.

Answer (score 4):

Tue Jun  2 06:40:01 2020
Your terminal (/dev/pts/0) has been idle for 63 min.
Press Enter key or you will be logged out any time after 56 min.

The above output is NOT standard sshd or any process of Linux OS.
I guess you are using a Nokia deployed system.
There is a private process /usr/sbin/KillIdleSessions to do such jobs as named.

Its configration file is:
/etc/security/kis.conf

Normally, this process is scheduled in root crontab.

Comment: Thanks for that info! I don't mind it timing out after 2 hours, but I don't like it warning me every 15 minutes, so I've changed the kis.conf settings.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
/usr/sbin/KillIdleSessions -disable
```

Reenable when done, or don't. Autologout after 24 hours make sense. Autologout every few minutes does not, especially as it isn't very good at detecting activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can let wget run in the background with `-b` option. The ssh session can be closed but the ssh process runs on. [source](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-run-wget-in-background.html)